# Solving linear recursions without constant depth in mathematica

Tags: recursion

Mathematica does not like this recurrence relation. I do not understand why?

```
RSolve[{a[0] == 1, 
  a[n] == 2 + 2 a[0] + 2 Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n - 2}] + a[n - 1], 
  a[1] == 3, a[2] == 7}, a, n]
Table[a[n] /. First[%], {n, 10}]
```

If I change the 1 in the sum to n-3 or something, that it seems to be okay.  But why can't I sum from 1 to n-2?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

```
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 3;
a[2] = 7;
a[n_] := If[n >= 3, 4 + 2 Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n - 2}] + a[n - 1]];
Table[a[n], {n, 0, 10}]
```

(*
{1, 3, 7, 17, 41, 99, 239, 577, 1393, 3363, 8119}
*)

```
FindSequenceFunction[Table[a[n], {n, 0, 10}]]
```

(*
1/2 ((1 - Sqrt[2])^#1 + (1 + Sqrt[2])^#1) &
*)

Comment: `Array[a, 11, 0]` would be shorter than `Table`. +1 however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Ah yes.  I started by editing the posers code, including the `Table`, whereas `Array` would be just a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to generate sequence:

```
in = {1, 3, 7};
f = {##, 2 Total@Most@{##2} + 4 + Last@{##}} &;
```

Now you can generate sequence of desired length, e.g. a[0],...,a[10] (8 extra elements)

```
Nest[f@@#&,in,8]
```

yielding: {1, 3, 7, 17, 41, 99, 239, 577, 1393, 3363, 8119}

or define function:

```
a[0] := 1;
a[1] := 3;
a[2] := 7;
a[n_] := Last@Nest[f @@ # &, in, n - 2]
```

and use, e.g,  `FindSequenceFunction[Nest[f @@ # &, in, 10]]` as David G, Stork.

This is just another way and I have voted +1 David G. Stork.